# Styling elements created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am a newbee so sorry if my question is basic.
i have written a code (with the help of the forum offcourse) where by clicking on an image another one appears and when you click on the new one, again another one appears and so on. 
the problem is i can not add an style to the code and make the images appear in different positions to make a layout.
can anyone here help me?
thank you so much

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> COOPER BLACK </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="style.css" media="screen">

</head>
```

```
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javaSCRIPT">

        var i = 1

        function imageClick() {
            if (! this.alreadyClicked)
                {
                addimage();
                counter();
                this.alreadyClicked = true;
                }
        }

        function addimage() {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "images/d"+i+".jpg";
            img.onclick = imageClick;
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

        function counter() {
            i = i + 1
        }

</script>

 <div class="first">
         <input class="first" type="image" src="images/d0.jpg" onclick="imageClick();">

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: use a class (eg `img.classname = 'fred';`) and apply the style to the class ...

Comment: i have done. but it does not work. i guess because it is an script

Comment: your script shows no such attempt, so ... you can also set style using `img.style.???` (I'll let you research the methods)

Comment: @Sina, what is pointing to `this.isClicked`, in your codes? Try making a variable on top named `isClicked`. Also showing some fiddle demo would be easier to debug.

Comment: thanks Jaroman but each appeared image will have a different style? how can make a class then? i know the basic methode but in here i don't know how to make classes for the script.

Comment: hi tika. that is written so that the nex image appears only by clicking on the image befor and not by clicking on any other images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the class attribute this way

```
img.setAttribute("class", "YourClassName");
```

Then apply the style to YourClassName in a CSS file/style tag. (Might also want to call the script after you load the CSS) Like so

```
.YourClassName { /* style here */ }
```

**Edit:**
You can also check if the elements are rendered well (the HTML tags have the class names and onClick methods) using the console (press F12 on the page)

Comment: silly question but where in my code should i add it? and how i make it understand for which image it is?
thnaks

Comment: Right after `var img = document.createElement("img");` because you are first creating a varaible and then making changes to it. Most of the functions are self-explanatory based on their names. And don't worry, the only silly questions are those which aren't asked q:

Comment: Also, just as a suggestion, you could do this to have a unique class for each image: `img.setAttribute("class", "imagesd"+i);` and in your css you can name your classes .imagesd1, .imagesd2 etc

Comment: yeah i got it. that is what i am trying to do. thank you so much for your help. i understand it now :)